# PHP: Is it possible to save a website, simulating a manual save?

Tags: php, save

I understand how to use fopen, file_get_contents, etc - but I'm curious to know if there is a way to generate a "manual save" on a webpage? As if I were to physically right-click > "Save As" > to Desktop?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to learn more about securing data. I didn't think it was possible to hide source code, but I recently found out that can be done by putting the code in JavaScript. So the "hidden code" won't appear in View Source, but it will still appear in Firefox Web Developer Tools and such.

So let's say I'm using JavaScript to secure my source code (as best as can be, that is). If someone were to Ctrl+U (View Source) my webpage (or fopen/file_get_contents), they would see:

```
<div class="StartofSecretSourceCode"></div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="StartofSecretSourceCode">
    <div class="Something">Some stuff and things</div>
</div>
```

In order for the user to see the full source code in this section, they would have to inspect the code in Firefox/Firebug/etc or **manually save the webpage**.

So I'm wondering if it's possible for someone to automate "manually saving" the webpage using PHP (or something else). And if so, I'm curious to know how you would do that in PHP. I hope that my question makes sense >.<

Comment: You seem to be operating from some false assumptions here.  Anything you send to the client will be visible to the client.  I'm not sure what you mean by something being "in JavaScript" and this somehow "not visible" to the user.  The user can see everything that's there.  As far as what you're asking, it *sounds like* what you're looking for is something called a "headless browser", which is a code component that acts like a browser (including executing JavaScript) but just has no UI.

Comment: Whatever you send to the client(i.e. browser), be it pure HTML, full blows website, JSON, XML, etc. it is still just given to the user. The browser might render the content, but it is in no way "hidden" or secure. Once you send it off to the world, whatever it is, it has been publicly shared. Only your backend code, which resides on the server is private.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guzzle library or curl to send request and save response (in the same way as browser - literally you can simulate browser) - so you can sent GET request and download page (and its assets like js files) and save it to disc from php side - it is no problem.

However if you want to protect your code dont send it to user but EXECUTE it on server side and return to user only RESULTS (in html file). This is standard and good way of code protection